# .length is not taking in Jasmine Karma unit testing

Tags: angular, ionic3, karma-jasmine, karma-coverage, angular-test

Could anyone please help me to resolve the below issue.

> Error: TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Component File:

```
 @Input()
   allPropertyLines: any[];

 @Input()
   completedPropertyLines: any[];

 allPropertyLength: number = 0;
 completedPropertyLength: number = 0;

  ngOnInit() {
      this.allPropertyLength = this.allPropertyLines.length;
      this.completedPropertyLength = this.completedPropertyLines.length;      
   }
```

Spec File:

```
 beforeEach(() => {
   fixture = TestBed.createComponent(ListPropertyComponent);
   comp = fixture.componentInstance;
   comp.ngOnInit();    
 });
it('should create component', () => expect(comp).toBeDefined());
```

Answer (score 1):

Thanks guys!! it works.

A simple thing missed to keep in mind that I should provide an input as given below.

comp.allPropertyLines = [{}].